# beamer: shadow broken

Tags: beamer

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{noto-sans}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\title{The Title}
\author{My Name}
\institute{My Institute}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

There is a white bar on the right edge of the box:

[image: white bar with Noto Sans]

The width of the white bar seems to be font dependent. If you replace `\usepackage{noto-sans}` by `\usepackage{lmodern}`, the bar is narrower:

[image: white bar with lmodern]

This is not a viewer issue, the white bar is also present on a printed page. I'm using MiKTeX. All packages are up to date.

How to fix this issue?

Note: There are other questions about broken shadows or white lines in beamer here on tex.stackexchange, but none seem to address exactly this issue.

Comment: how do you compile?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm using pdftex.

Comment: Confirming the result under LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have now tried pdfTeX, XeTeX and LuaTeX. The result is the same for all three engines.

Comment: I can reproduce your error; then I update the package; and your code now produces no error

Comment: @Symbol1 Yes, this bug was fixed in beamer version 3.64 (see [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/621805/227621)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug was fixed in `beamer` version 3.64. It has been discussed at the GitHub page of the `beamer` project (see [this issue](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/647)).

If you compile the MWE using version 3.64, the shadow is fine:

[image: image showing the box with shadow]

(Unfortunately, according to the linked GitHub discussion, there are now new issues with shadows in other situations.)